# Firebase Query by Inner Array Values

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

By selecting a value from a drop-down list in my Application I need to get a list of every Object that contains the selected value in its inner node 'foodtype'.

I have the following structure in my Firebase database:

```
restaurants
  - key: "12345"
    - name: "Salad house"
    - address: "Etc etc etc"
    - foodtypes
        - 0: "Salad"
        - 1: "Fastfood"
        - 2: "Seafood"
...
```

For example: If I select "Salad", "Fastfood" or "Seafood" I should get the object above in my restaurants list. But if I select "Japanese food" I should get none (or any other record that contains that).

Is there a way to do this in Firebase without creating lots of concatenated fields/values? I would really appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: if you select `Salad` you want to get foodtypes?

Comment: If I select "Salad" I want to get the whole restaurant object because it contains that value in its 'foodtypes' inner node.

Comment: im not sure if that is possible, but if you remove `foodtypes` and just add `- 0: "Salad"
        - 1: "Fastfood"
        - 2: "Seafood"` it will be possible

Comment: I could remove the `foodtypes` node as you say and create 3 fields called `foodtype1`, `foodtype2`, `foodtype3`, but by doing that I would set a fixed amount of `food types` allowed per `restaurant`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with Cloud Firestore query, not Firebase RTDB(Realtime database) query.

If you want approach it with Firebase RTDB, your database should look like this.

```
restaurants
  - key: "12345"
    - name: "Salad house"
    - address: "Etc etc etc"
    - foodtype: 0 (or 1 or 2 ...)
...
```

You can also use string like "Salad", "Fastfood", "Seafood" but since the name could be changed in the future, I would use integer as constant variable and define it in your javascript code as `const FOODTYPE_SALAD = 0`, `const FOODTYPE_FASTFOOD = 1`.

Finally you can get list as below code.

```
return restaurantsRef.orderByChild('foodtype').equalTo(FOODTYPE_SALAD).once('value').then(snap => {
    // TODO: ...
});
```

But this way has some disadvantages.

For example you cannot sort list as you want. What if you want to sort restaurant list as registered date?

Therefore best option for Firebase RTDB in this situation is denormalize your database and flatten the database.

You will need [Server side Fan-out on Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://hackernoon.com/firebase-server-side-fan-out-722e825a05fb).

This is final appearance of your database tables.

```
restaurants
  - key: "12345"
    - name: "Salad house"
    - address: "Etc etc etc"
    - foodtype: 0
  - key: "22222"
    - name: "Fastfood house"
    - address: "Etc etc etc"
    - foodtype: 1
  - key: "33333"
    - name: "Seafood house"
    - address: "Etc etc etc"
    - foodtype: 2

restaurants-salad
  - key: "12345"
    - name: "Salad house"
    - address: "Etc etc etc"
    - foodtype: 0

restaurants-fastfood
  - key: "22222"
    - name: "Fastfood house"
    - address: "Etc etc etc"
    - foodtype: 1

restaurants-seafood
  - key: "33333"
    - name: "Seafood house"
    - address: "Etc etc etc"
    - foodtype: 2
...
```

Remember that `restaurants` should have all original `restaurant` object datas.

Comment: I'm really struggling on accepting this level of denormalization (I have been working with relational databases for ages), but I think I must go for it.

Comment: @Marcelo Remember that denormalization is normal in NoSQL database, it makes better performance than rdb.

Comment: check this: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html

Comment: It must be thankful to accept my answer if it was helpful to you :)